# Delay the opening of other tabs, until the first tab loads completely

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome Extension, using JS that takes a user prompted URL parses some variables out of it, and then loads multiple tabs based on the information that was parsed.  The issue, is that before I can do that, I need to wait for a login tab to complete loading, before trying to open the other tabs.  So the preferred order would be

1. User Prompt
2. Load Login Tab
3. Wait until Login Tab is loaded
4. Open remaining tabs.

My code is as below

```
    var URL_Proper = prompt ('Paste the Become-User-ID URL below:');
    var User_ID = URL_Proper.substring(URL_Proper.indexOf('?become_user_id=')+16,URL_Proper.length);
    var Domain = 'https://' + URL_Proper.substring(8,URL_Proper.substring(8,URL_Proper.length).indexOf('/')+8);

    var win = window.open(Domain + 'login_key', '_blank'); 

    var win = window.open(URL_Proper, '_blank');
    var win = window.open(URL_Proper.substring(0,URL_Proper.indexOf('?')), '_blank');
    var win = window.open(Domain.substring(0)+'/users/'+User_ID, '_blank');
```

The delay I would like would be between the (Domain + 'login_key', '_blank'); and the other three tabs, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  My guess is this would be better served with chrome.tabs.create, but I am such a beginner that I can't figure out how to do that, nor can I figure out how to make the code wait for the first tab to load, before opening all the other tabs.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, my suggestion is then to read the [`chrome.tabs` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) carefully. They may help. This question is too broad.

Comment: I apologize, I have read that, as well as I could, and gleaned nothing from it.  To clarify my question, how do I open a tab using chrome.tabs.create instead of var win= window.open, because I can't even get that far.  Once I am able to do that, what command would best assist me in telling the other tabs to wait to open until the first tab has loaded completely?

Again apologies, I'm brand new at this.